# I got a 64195 error in memtest. What should I do?

Tags: memory, memtest86+, memtest

I have a [Lenovo Essential G580](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/essential/g-series/g580/) (59-358263) Laptop (3rd Gen Ci5/ 4GB/ 500GB/ DOS) and running Windows 10 Pro (latest version).

I’m getting blue screen of death (BSOD) a lot, mainly while gaming so I ran memtest.

I have [a video I posted on YouTube](https://youtu.be/egAkFO3H6So) of the issue of which might help you recognize the problem.

Comment: Just cause I'm not familiar with that favour of memtest, and this looks catastrophically awful, could you give memtest from a linux livedisk and/or the memtest option in modern copies of windows a shot?

Comment: Are there any BIOS settings that refer to RAM speed or voltage? Is this just the RAM that came with the machine or did you add/change anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I interpret the statistics of a memtest run?](http://superuser.com/questions/326078/how-do-i-interpret-the-statistics-of-a-memtest-run) or [I have been told to accept one error with Memtest86+](http://superuser.com/questions/521086/i-have-been-told-to-accept-one-error-with-memtest86).  If your computer is having *any* errors in Memtest, test each DIMM individually.  That should give you an idea of what the issue is.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i haven't changed anything,everything is just same as i but it

Comment: @DavidPostill no,it's not. in that ques,i have asked for pc isn't starting that was also happening before i run memtest

Comment: @AnurodhTripathi You should have updated the other question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, memtest errors typically should mean your ram is faulty, and by the looks of it quite a lot of this.

With a problem like this I'd

1. replace the ram (and if you have another laptop of a similar vintage, check with known good ram!)
2. If that doesn't help, something else may be broken (like your memory controller). Considering sandy and ivy bridge have the memory controller in the CPU, if replacing the ram dosen't help, I'd probably think you would end up replacing the laptop.

As an aside, it seems some flavours of linux actually have a patch that lets you blacklist bad ram. I've never used it before but its worth a look if you do end up finding its bad ram, and experiment with it. I'd hardly consider it production grade but its worth messing with. I'd refer you to [U&L for more details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75059/how-to-blacklist-a-correct-bad-ram-sector-according-to-memtest86-error-indicati)

Comment: Oh dear. That would be information that would have been handy to have linked. A voltage surge could result in both my hypothesis.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek i can't run another memtest right now(but i will provide u result when i run memtest) because laptop is not starting(again).so the only choice is left that find the faulty module of memory and replace it with new one(i don't have another similar laptop).i know people are marking it duplicate and i have checked this ques - "How do I interpret the statistics of a memtest run?" .i want to know that, is this normal getting  64195 errors,and what could be reason faulty memory,because its only 2 year old(time from i bought it).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek you've noticed that i have fluctuated power supply in my home,once my laptop charger is get damaged because of this so i bought another but not branded(not of lenovo).when i charge my laptop using that charger ,sometime i get miner electric shock from the laptop.do u think that this could be the reason memory fault